# List all the customer IDs and last names who have made more than 2 orders

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I Need The Code For Following 
**Customer Table**

```
CREATE TABLE customer (
  customer_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  last_name VARCHAR(255),
  city VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  State_ VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  zip VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL
)
```

**Order Table**

```
CREATE TABLE order_(
order_number INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
Customer_ID integer FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES customer (customer_id) Not NULL,
Date_ date NOT NULL,
)
```

How To Display customer IDs and last names who have made more than 2 orders
any one help please

Comment: SO is not a "write my code for me" site. At least show some effort!

Comment: That's y i come out with at least that i have done so far rather than telling stories

Comment: Where does it say what you have done so far?

Comment: at least i have come with the tables and attributes,is that not enough to give me a solution

Comment: That is not the point. Yes, you gave enough information for your problem to be solved. This is, however, a very basic concept. You should have been able to find the information to solve it yourself. The point is, you have a problem and you ask SO to solve it for you, instead of trying yourself. If you had a query where you attempted to solve the problem, but encountered a problem of some kind, that is the point to turn to SO. Like I said, SO is not here to write your code for you, it's to help you write your own code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT customer_id, last_name
FROM dbo.customer
WHERE customer_id IN (
    SELECT Customer_ID
    FROM order_
    GROUP BY Customer_ID
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
Select customer_id,last_name From  Customer
Where customer_id in 
(Select customer_id From Order group by customer_id having count(customer_id) > 2 )
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, unfortunately show some error.