# Return id, first name, and last name of authors who have written more than two novels

Tags: mysql, database

I have three tables in my database

Author: aid  | fname | lname

Book: isbn | title | btype | price | pub_date | pid

Written_by: isbn (references book.isbn) | aid (references author.aid)

I am trying to return the first and last name of all authors who have written more than two books of btype "novel". I did find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33937944/list-all-the-customer-ids-and-last-names-who-have-made-more-than-2-orders) question which will select authors who have written more than two books in general, but I can't figure out how to modify it to focus on novels specifically. Any suggestions?

```
select aid, fname, lname 
from author 
where aid in (
    select aid
    from written_by
        join book on book.isbn = written_by.isbn
    group by aid
    having count(*) > 2
);
```

edit: Figured it out. Added `where btype = "novel"` before `group by` and it now works as intended.

Comment: the subquery can use a `where clause` too. If that query focused on novels would you have an answer?

Comment: I was just about to edit my answer to say that I changed `group by` to `where btype = "novel"` and it worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: don't "change" the group by you still need that just  `ADD` the where clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several way to form this query. You have used `IN()` here is an alternative which you should be aware of.

Using an inner join

```
select aid, fname as "First Name", lname as "Last Name"
from author a
inner join (
    select aid
    from written_by
        join book on book.isbn = written_by.isbn
    where btype = 'novel'
    group by aid
    having count(*) > 2
    ) g on a.aid = g.aid
```

Note use the single quotes for literals such as `'novel'` double quotes are used for identities such as column aliases containing spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Added `where btype = "novel"` before `group by` and it now works as intended.

Comment: If you are going to add your own answer, please learn about acceptance and upvoting ....  "click the tick" because that let's others know the question is done. You get 2 rep points for an acceptance... but not on your own answers of course.